# Send string to void

Tags: c++, mfc

I am writing a image acquisition GUI using an SDK which requires MFC. I am not really familiar with MFC in C++, but I have gone far enough to create a directory chooser in which to save files. The problem is the MFC button I made returns TCHAR, the SDK requires const char* as an input. When I run my program the images are sent to the directory in which the VS solution lives not where I assigned a path.

I will include the code below:

```
void CGrabDlg::OnGrab()
{
    m_statusWnd.SetWindowText("Grabing...");

    if(m_Xfer->Grab())
    {
        UpdateMenu();
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        int m_StartFrame; 
        const char* m_Options="-format tiff"; 
        int fileCount=1; 

        while(fileCount<10) 
        {  
            CString counter; //file counter 
            CString image = "image"; 
            counter.Format("%03d",fileCount); 
            CString imageType = ".tiff";
            CString fileName = pathName + image + counter + imageType; 
            const char* x = (LPCTSTR) fileName;
            fileCount++; 
            m_StartFrame = (m_Buffers == NULL) ? 0 : m_Buffers->GetIndex(); 
            m_Buffers->Next(); 
            m_Buffers->Save(x, m_Options);
            m_statusWnd.SetWindowText(pathName);
        } 

    }
}
```

Here is the directory chooser I hacked together:

```
void CGrabDlg::OnBnClickedChooseDir()
{

    BROWSEINFO   bi; 
    ZeroMemory(&bi,   sizeof(bi)); 
    TCHAR   szDisplayName[MAX_PATH]; 
    szDisplayName[0]    =   '\0';  

    bi.hwndOwner        =   NULL; 
    bi.pidlRoot         =   NULL; 
    bi.pszDisplayName   =   szDisplayName; 
    bi.lpszTitle        =   _T("Please select a folder for storing acquired images :"); 
    //bi.ulFlags          =   BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS;
    bi.ulFlags          =   BIF_USENEWUI;
    bi.lParam           =   NULL; 
    bi.iImage           =   0;  
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    LPITEMIDLIST   pidl   =   SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);
    TCHAR   szPathName[MAX_PATH]; 
    if   (NULL   !=   pidl)
    {
         BOOL bRet = SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl,szPathName);
         if(FALSE == bRet)
              return;
         AfxMessageBox(szPathName);
         CString pathName = szPathName;
         m_statusWnd.SetWindowText(szPathName);
    }
}
```

The Window text returns the correct path directory (m_statusWnd.SetWindowText(szPathName);), but when I try to append the path to the final input to save to image, it fails to be present (CString fileName = pathName + image + counter + imageType; ).

Comment: What happens if you Debug through the program? Are the proper path-separator characters present between pieces of the path?

Comment: What's `pathName` as used in `CGrabDlg::OnGrab`? Where is it declared, where is it initialized? It's clearly not the same variable as `pathName` in `CGrabDlg::OnBnClickedChooseDir` - that one is a local variable.

Comment: @Igor I declared it as a public CString in the header file, both of these functions are in the same cpp file. Though it is a possibility that I am being dense.

Comment: The line `CString pathName = szPathName;` defines a local variable, unrelated to `CGrabDlg::pathName` member variable (which I assume exists, though your code doesn't show it). The local variable is initialized, but is never used afterwards. The member variable is never touched, and likely holds an empty string.

Comment: @Igor you are correct, I made a dumb mistake that should have been solved quickly, but for some reason took way too long to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> const char* x = (LPCTSTR) fileName;

Such a type-cast will only work if your project is being compiled for ANSI, where `TCHAR` maps to `char`.  If compiling for Unicode instead, `TCHAR` would map to `wchar_t`, and you cannot assign a `wchar_t*` to a `char*`, you would have to use `WideCharToMultiByte()` to convert the data from UTF-16 to ANSI.

> ```
> if (NULL != pidl)
> {
>     ...
>     CString pathName = szPathName;
>     m_statusWnd.SetWindowText(szPathName);
> }
> ```

You are assigning `szPathName` to a local temp `pathName` variable that is different than the `pathName` variable used in this statement:

> CString fileName = pathName + image + counter + imageType;

And as such, this statement:

```
m_statusWnd.SetWindowText(pathName);
```

Should be displaying a blank string.

Thus `filename` will never receive the path selected with `SHBrowseForFolder()`.  Its value would start with the `image` variable, making the resulting `fileName` value relative to the calling process's *Current Working Directory*, which explains why the file is getting saved relative to the VS Solution's folder.

You need to change this line:

```
CString pathName = szPathName;
```

To this instead:

```
pathName = szPathName;
```

So that you are assigning `szPathName` to the `pathName` member of the `CGrabDlg` class.

Comment: Thank you, that was a foolish mistake on my part. I also had to append the fileName with pathName + "\\" + image + counter + imageType; but it works now!

Comment: Have a look at [`PathAddBackslash()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773561.aspx), [`PathCombine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571.aspx), [`PathAppend()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565.aspx), and other related functions.